# how to use different subdomains on same java webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, path, subdomain, tomcat7

I want to map different paths on a java webapp to different subdomains with tomcat7. 


`like: sub1.domain.com <- domain.com/sub1/`
`sub2.domain.com <- domain.com/sub2/`..

I found some solutions with different java webapp but I didn't find anything for mapping folders to subdomains.

Comment: This would be easier to do with a web server (reverse proxy) in front of tomcat. Then you can map the domains to the context-roots easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve different subdomains by enable tomcat's ajp connector and use an apache server with mod_jk in front of the tomcat. In the apache server configuration you can create virtual hosts and use the JkMount directive to mount your webapp.

Inside the virtualHost Directive:

```
JkMount URL_PREFIX WORKER_NAME
e.g.
JkMount /sub1 sub1worker
```

And update the workers.properties file

```
worker.list=sub1Worker,sub2worker

worker.sub1worker.type=ajp
worker.sub1worker.host=yourtomcathost.com
worker.sub1worker.port=8009 # default port
```